# Start Linux process/script via web interface

Tags: linux, java, process, logging, webserver

I have a bunch of Java programs/shellscripts that needs to be manually started every now and then (mostly in the mornings), and stopped every evening (same there). I would like a possibility to start the scripts via a web-interface. Would also like to be able to look at logs.

Can I do that with a standard Ubuntu installation, or do I need some 3rd party tools?

-- edit --

I understand that the UN*X WAY is to do this with crontab etc. Also that writing a simple controller that could start/stop processes via a web interface isnt that big of a thing.

I just wondered whether there existed some kind of process monitor framework, that could start/stop/restart processes, maybe deal with dependencies (if this process crashes, that one must be restarted). All together with a neat Web interface (together with headless control possibilities of course).

Such a tool/framework could offload a lot of basic work to "simple users".

Rundeck seems promising, but maybe I was looking for something more customizable.

Comment: Why not schedule them with a crontab and a timeout?

Comment: Because I said in the question I want to start and stop them manually. It would be good if course to have some scheduled starts/stops too, but I need to have the manual control. And I want it to be easy to understand even for a non-tech user. Plus, would be super if one could check the logfile for each process too in some way.

Comment: Sounds like you're going to be writing some custom software to me. Ubuntu has web servers available in the repositories. As for your "admin interface", there are some (like say [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)) but I don't think it has the capabilities you're requesting (especially "easy to understand even for a non-tech user").

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) for this. It's a stand-alone Java process which can be accessed through a webbrowser. The admin can specify jobs which wil run either a command or a script. A user can then run the job (optionally with parameters).

Output will be sent back to the browser. There is also logging of past-run jobs.

Here is a screenshot from the manual, using jobs:
[image]

Editing jobs:

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting and I have installed it for review, however it feels a little bit like using a Destroyer to sink a rowing boat. It features the possibility to run a command on multiple targets which is nice though, however not applicable in this particular case.

Comment: I have found supervisor (http://supervisord.org/). How would you say this compares to RunDeck?

Comment: @PeterAndersson supervisord seems more like a tool to run jobs automatically. Rundeck is made to be used manually by n00b users.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of web based terminal emulators out there.  I used one in the past, but forgot which one it was.

Check out this [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20web%20based%20terminal%20emulator&oq=linux%20web%20based%20ter&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.7039j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=linux%20web%20terminal%20emulator) for a list of them.